# Linq correlated subquery to same table on multiple columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I've looked at several other questions related to correlated subqueries but it's still not clear to me how to accomplish what I need.  I'm using Entity Framework and C#, and have a table called STEWARDSHIP with the following columns:

- STEWARDSHIP_ID (the primary key)
- SITE_ID
- VISIT_DATE
- VISIT_TYPE_ID

I need to identify cases where the same combination of SITE_ID, VISIT_DATE, VISIT_TYPE_ID exists more than once because it could represent a duplicate entry made by end users in error, and then I need to report on the details of these entries.  In SQL I would do this by joining to the temporary result of a GROUP BY/HAVING like so:

```
SELECT * FROM stewardship AS s2,
(SELECT site_id, visit_type_id, CAST(visit_date AS DATE) AS visit_date
    FROM stewardship
    GROUP BY site_id, visit_type_id, CAST(visit_date AS DATE)
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS s
WHERE s2.site_id = s.site_id
AND s2.visit_type_id = s.visit_type_id
AND CAST(s2.visit_date AS DATE) = s.visit_date
```

What's the best way to accomplish this in Linq?

Comment: If you're open to a different approach, I'll post a solution that uses a self-join instead of a correlated sub-query. It would also perform quite a bit better (even its SQL equivalent, which I'll include as well). If you're bent on the correlated sub-query though, I'll think on it.

Comment: Sure, I'd like to see what you've got in mind.  I'm just interested in getting the right results with decent performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're open to a different approach that *should* be more performant, here is the new SQL to get what I think you're after.

```
select distinct s1.*
from stewardship s1
    inner join stewardship s2 on 
        s1.stewardship_id <> s2.stewardship_id and
        s1.site_id = s2.site_id and
        s1.visit_type_id = s2.visit_type_id and
        cast(s1.visit_date as date) = cast(s2.visit_date as date)
order by s1.site_id, s1.visit_type_id
```

Now, to translate that to LINQ, you can use the following statement.

```
var duplicates = (
    from s in Stewardships
    join s2 in Stewardships
        on new { s.Site_id, s.Visit_type_id, s.Visit_date.Date } equals new { s2.Site_id, s2.Visit_type_id, s2.Visit_date.Date }
    where s.Stewardship_id != s2.Stewardship_id
    select s)
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(s => s.Site_id)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Visit_type_id)
```

Note that you cannot use anything other than an equijoin for expression joins, so I had to put the non-equijoin (ensuring our matches aren't on the same record via PK) in the where expression. You could also accomplish this with lambdas via the Except() extension method.

The order by is there for readability of the results and to match the SQL statement above.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This seems to give me the expected results @ventaur.  Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly similar to what you've already got.

```
from s in context.stewardships
group s by new {s.site_id, s.visit_type_id, visit_date} into g
where g.Count() > 1
select g;
```

This would give you groups of stewardships with similar values. You could "flatten" those results with a SelectMany afterward, but you might find them more useful to work with in groups.

Note that you may need to use SqlFunctions or something to do the equivalent of the cast to date.

Comment: I know how to perform the group by in Linq but I need to reference columns like stewardship_id that are not part of the group by.  How do I do that?